# How do I fix the references to a VS project in references tab?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, directory

I have some broken references from a repository that I connected to, and the repo includes all of the solutions, but still the references are broken...the screen shots are what I have. How can I fix the broken references to the projects?

[image: The solution references:]

[image: The folder containing the project referenced]

[image: The folder containing the solution with the]

Comment: you will need to remove the references one by one and re-add them pointing to the correct folders also make sure your namespaces are correct in the project .cs files..

Comment: @MethodMan that is not correct. You don't need to remove the references if they're broken. You can just add a reference to the same assembly (but correct path of course) and Visual Studio will overwrite the broken reference. You could also just open the .csproj file in an editor and change the reference paths there. If your references moved to another location, you can do a find&replace on the filepath for example.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler I believe that if he copied it over from another source and did not download and or have his code checked into `TFS` for instance then yes he would.. because it because a path issue either way this sounds like the project references are there but the actual location of where the dll's reside are not pointing to the correct location.. lets wait to hear back from the OP to see how the issue was resolved it at all that..

Comment: @MethodMan oh you mean those are projects in the same solution? That could get tricky, never had to deal with that before.

Answer (score 1):

Check, if by any chance the referencing project targets a different version of .NET framework (especially if it is lower). 
Right click project in Solution Explorer, choose "Properties" => "Application" => "Target Framework".